# Using MotionEvent

Tags: android

From my knowledge x and y starts at the top left of the screen as 0,0

> My question is there a calculation to get a positioning in the event? or another way(eg. another new class or method within this class)?

Now the question is vague so I want to add an example:

I remember in math close you have 4 sections in a graph top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right.

Using the graph style to get variables in:

1. Getting position from top left to bottom left.
2. Getting position from bottom right to top right
3. Getting position from top left to bottom right

Comment: Your question is unanswerable

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` then you can calculate coordinates in any section of graph used in math class.

1. x, height - y
2. x, height - y
3. width - x, height - y

Comment: How would you know which section it would be if you the values?

Comment: Would you do an initial gathering of values of what is the half of screen height and width?